# Launch Snap-in chat from Lightning Component in Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, liveagent, lightning-community, snap-ins

We currently have Snap-in chat enabled in a Lightning Community. The client would like to launch the snap-in chat button from a custom lightning component somewhere on the community page. For example, the navbar in the community would have a "Chat" button that should open the standard snap in chat button on the bottom of the page.

Has anyone tried this before? Any documentation on calling snap ins from Lightning Components in community? My searches have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Hey there! I am trying to do this as well.  Were you able to find a solution? Thanks